# Search a buffer for hex values and return the resulting location in C

Tags: c, search, hex, buffer

I'm new to C, so I apologize for any "obvious issues".

I'm trying to search a buffer for a set of hex-values. I'm trying to put it into a function because I'm going to have to search for multiple sets of them.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#define bin_buff_size (1024 * 1500)
unsigned char *bin_buff;
int i, hex_location, reset_i, hex_i, fix_location_1, buff_size;
unsigned char hex_string_search_1[] = {0x5e, 0x00, 0x75, 0x0d, 0x68, 0xb4, 0x2c, 0x63};

<other code here>

int get_location_from_buffer(unsigned char *needle, unsigned char *haystack, size_t haystack_size) {
    // Find the location of the hex-values in the buffer
    for (i = 0; i < haystack_size; i++) {
        // Reset hex_value because I will need to do this for multiple sets of hex values
        for (reset_i = 0; reset_i <= 7; reset_i++) {
            hex_value[reset_i] = 0x00;
          }

        // Set hex_value equal to the next section of the haystack
        for (hex_i = 0; hex_i <= 7; hex_i++) {
            hex_value[hex_i] = haystack[i + hex_i];
            printf("hex_value[%i] = %s\n",hex_i,hex_value[hex_i]); // Print the resulting hex-value for this sub-location
          }
        printf("hex_value = %s\n",hex_value);  // Print the entire hex_value

        // Check if needle equals haystack, and if so, return the resulting location
        if (needle == hex_value){
            printf("Found the first value at %i", i);
          }else{
            printf("Havent found the first value yet!\n");
          }
      }
    return i;
}


fix_location_1 = get_location_from_buffer(hex_string_search_1, bin_buff, buff_size);
```

The problem that I am having is that this is my output:

```
hex_value[0] = (null)
hex_value[1] = (null)
hex_value[2] = (null)
hex_value[3] = (null)
hex_value[4] = (null)
hex_value[5] = (null)
hex_value[6] = (null)
hex_value[7] = (null)
hex_value =
Havent found the first value yet!
<The above is repeated multiple times>
```

It looks like this line:

```
hex_value[hex_i] = haystack[i + hex_i];
```

isn't actually pulling data from the buffer like I am thinking it should. Is someone able to point out what I'm doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("hex_value[%i] = %s\n",hex_i,hex_value[hex_i]);
```

should be

```
printf("hex_value[%i] = %x\n",hex_i,hex_value[hex_i]);
```

You are printing a raw value, not a string.

Comment: Is there a difference between %x and 0x%02x (from paulsm4 above) ?

Comment: The "0x" is printed verbatim, this is a good idea so you know the value is hexadecimal (not decimal, or octal, or...). The "%02x" is the format directive; it has three parts: '0' means print leading zeros, '2' means use a field width of 2, which is sufficient for an 8-bit byte, and 'x' means use hexadecimal format. The simple "%x" that I used just means use hex; this will not be fixed width, and will not have leading zeros. I usually use "0x%02x" just as @paulsm4 suggested.

Answer (score 1):

Several observations:

1) One problem is that you should use "0x%02x" (or "$0x2x", or whatever) to print a binary hex value.  Instead of "%s".  Which prints a string (character array), not a hex binary (single value).

2) "null" == "0" which implies you're not finding *anything*.

3) Q: Are you sure you're initializing the buffer correctly?

4) I haven't looked at it carefully, but Q: are you sure about your search algorithm?

5) Q: would you consider a recursive algorithm?

Just a few thoughts...

'Hope that helps ... at least a little bit

Comment: 1) Thanks, that makes it "look" a lot better so far.

2 & 3) Good question. Maybe I'm not. Is there a way that I can var_dump(buffer) ?

4) Not sure at all! I think it should work but that's why I'm here asking |:)

5) How would that be different? Isn't it just coming at the same problem from the opposite side of the buffer? Yes, I am willing, I just don't understand how it's different

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues in your code.
The main issue: `if (needle == hex_value)` is only compares pointers, not contents of them.
Use `strncmp` to compare content of two string.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
if (needle == hex_value){
```

is comparing the two addresses, not the values stored at those addresses. I don't think that comparison is what you want...